# Make the whole shape clickable using HTML and css

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the text, it is clickable. But I want to make the whole shape clickable. I tried but it's going outside the shape. How can we make the shape (only within the shape) clickable? Here's the code I tried. What should I do to make the whole shape clickable? Can anyone please help me with this?

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.diamond {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
      display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #ffffff;
FONT-SIZE: 13PX;
    FONT-WEIGHT: 600;
}
.diamond:after {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ef1717;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 22px);  
  width: calc(100% - 22px); 
  border-radius: 18%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: -1;
  }
#diamond:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
       transform: scale(1.1);
}
    a.int_link{
    text-decoration: none;
    COLOR: #FFFF;
    FONT-WEIGHT: 700;
    font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:99%;padding:5px;">
<tr>
<td>
<div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem...</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div>
</td>
<td>
<a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem..</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem..</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem..</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a>
</td>
<td>
<a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem..</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a>
</td>
    <td>
<a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="diamond" id="diamond"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a><div class="meet" style="margin-top:45px;"><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">lorem..</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a></div><a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
</a>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: you can try some [`map and area tags`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp) or try putting the whole shape into a `label` tag

Answer (score 0):

### I don't know if you would like this idea of mine

```css
.changed{
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
      display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    color: #ffffff;
FONT-SIZE: 13PX;
    FONT-WEIGHT: 600;
}

.changed:after{
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  content: '';
  height: calc(100% - 22px);  
  width: calc(100% - 22px); 
  border-radius: 18%;
  transform: rotateX(45deg) rotateZ(45deg);
  z-index: -1;

}

#changed:hover{

  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
   transform: scale(1.1);

}
```

```html
        <td>
     
        <div class="changed" id="changed">
            <a href=" " class="int_link" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">
            <span style="display: block; position: relative; top: 1rem; left: 1rem; padding-top:32px; width: 87px; height: 81px;">Changed</span>
            </a>
        </div>
   
        </td>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.